# Click not working with react component + capypara

Tags: ruby, testing, reactjs, capybara, react-rails

I've a react component that when I click in a icon, the state change and then I put a input instead of the icon.

When I try to simulate that on my test, using capybara the component doesn't change.

There's any chance that the click doesn't work at the component because of the capybara? Or just not work because it's a react component?

Component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.editable ? this.renderEditableComponent() : this.renderNotEditableComponent() }
    </div>
) }

  renderEditableComponent() {
   return (
    <EditableDeliverLimit
      value={ this.state.value }
      handleClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this) } />
  ) }

  renderNotEditableComponent() {
    return (
      <NotEditableDeliverLimit
       value={ this.state.value }
       handleClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this) } />
  ) }
```

Test:

```
Then "should successfuly change deliver limit" do
  wait_for_selector_appearance("##{ad_table_row_id(@ad)} .ad-table-row-deliver-limit span")
  find("##{ad_table_row_id(@ad)} .ad-table-row-deliver-limit span").click
  wait_for_selector_disappearance("##{ad_table_row_id(@ad)} .ad-table-row-deliver-limit span")
end
```

Comment: Does the code work outside of capybara? Are you able to share some of your code so that we can rule that out as being a problem?

Comment: Yes! When I test outside the test, everything works fine. I'll edit my question to put some code.

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: @TomWalpole webkit and poltergeist

Comment: @Marina. What version of PhantomJS are you using with poltergeist? And what version of Qt did you build capybara-WebKit with?

Comment: @TomWalpole Poltergeist: 1.6.0 and Qt: 4.8.7

Answer (score 0):

The version of PhantomJS and Qt WebKit you are using are outdated and don't support Function.prototype.bind which is required by React. Upgrade to PhantomJS 2.1.1+ and rebuild capybara-WebKit with Qt 5.5.1

Comment: After install qt5, was removed the qtWebkit. What can I do?

Comment: @Marina you installed 5.6 not 5.5.1

Comment: I installed qt55 then rebuilded capybara-webkit and still didn't work

Comment: @Marina what do you mean by "didnt work"? Do you get an error, nothing happens? Details are important

Comment: Sorry! The test didn't work. The test still does'nt click at my component. There're no erros, the test just don't pass because it doesn't click at my component

Comment: @Marina what about using poltergeist with updated PhantomJS?

Comment: I tried to use phantomjs-polyfill too and the click still didn't work in the test

Comment: @Marina For the test not to pass there has to be some sort of error raised.  Does your "wait_for_selector_disappearance" fail?  If so what does it output?  What exactly does wait_for_selector_disappearance do since thats not a Capybara method.

Comment: wait_for_selector_disappearance waits for a element to disappear. Since my component change from a label to a input and from a icon to a button when a click in the icon, I wait for him to disappear but this don't happens. The method wait_for_selector_disappearance has I timeout and the error is: RuntimeError: Timeout for '#ad_57aa442d98c11959bd000010 span' disappearance reached!

But I have two clicks with bind, one for click at the component and one to click outside of the component and the click outside the component works, so I don't think that the problem is with the bind :/

Comment: if you have other react behaviors that are working then there are only a few  possible causes. 1. you're not actually clicking the correct element - 2. you're not actually using the driver you think you are in this test - 3. you have a JS error in your test - 4. Your wait_for_... method isn't correct.   For #4 that method isn't even necessary since Capybara will wait automatically and provide useful errors instead of just Timeout -  with RSpec - `expect(page).to have_no_selector("##{ad_table_row_ ...")`  or without RSpec - `page.assert_no_selector("##{ad_table_row_ ...")`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot try to fix this test anymore, but thank you very much for all the help and patience